# how to form the combinations of different notes that add up to 4 which is given by the user?

Tags: c++17, c++14, combinations, concept

You are given some amount of money and notes of different values, determine how many

ways notes can be organized to get the same amount of money. Each note is available in

abundant quantity so that it can be used any number of times.

Example

n = 3

cm]-[8, 3, 1, 21

There are 3 ways in which m distinct notes can be arranged to create the amount of

money

(1, 1, 1), (1.2) and (3)

Input Format

The first line contains integers and m, where:

n represents the amount

of money m represents various distinct values of notes

More

Contest ends in a day

Submissions: 4 Max Score: 100

Rate This Challenge:

Difficulty: Medium

The second line contains a list c containing the value of each note type

Constraints

1 - 10000

1 c m co 10

1 <= c() <= 100

Output Format

The output will be a single value

Sample Input 0

Sample Output 0

Explanation 0

Possible configuration of notes are:

(1,1,1,1)

(1,1,2)

(2,2)

(3,1)

Comment: in nutshell the user has entered the sum of 4 and we can use 3 different notes (i.e. 1 ,2 & 3) rspv by using this we have to total count the number of combinations we can generate amount 4 (in this case output would be just 4 as {1 1 1 1} {1 3} {2 2} {2 1 1}  )

Comment: I suppose you are expected to write some code for this.

Comment: algorithm just logically thinking

Comment: This just looks like a homework question. What code have you written? What problems did you have with the code?